# Object-URL alike way to play local audio files in Chrome for Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I have a media player that uses object URL's to load files 'in an instant'. However, Chrome for Android [doesn't support object URL's](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227476). what would be the best way to work around this problem? I was thinking about detecting wether the browser supports it, and then fall back on a file reader with data-URL's (`readAsArrayBuffer`).
I have already read through many questions, referring to using the web-audio-API. I however use this, but with `createMediaElement`, where the audio element plays the music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as it is, Chrome for Android doesn't support `URL.createObjectURL()`, we should indeed use `webkitURL.createObjectURL()`.